# Two variable adjunctions in poset-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

Adjoints between posets are (monotone or antitone) Galois connections; monads correspond to closure operators; what is a [two-variable adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/two-variable+adjunction) in this low-categorical setting?

I'm able to write the bare definition, of course. What I seek is intuition, and possibly an instance of this structure, on a triple of poset $P,Q,R$, possibly under a different name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important special case of a 2-variable adjunction is a biclosed monoidal structure on a category, such as a cartesian closed category.  A cartesian closed poset (with finite joins as well) is called a [Heyting algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting%20algebra), and corresponds to intuitionistic logic in the same way that Boolean algebras correspond to classical logic.  In particular, every Boolean algebra is a Heyting algebra and hence is equipped with a biclosed monoidal structure.

Comment: This is sort of the paradigmatic example, and I have clear in mind why, but then I think the next step would be to say what a $\bf Heyt$-enriched category, which is tensored and cotensored, is called outside category theory.

Comment: I presume you mean a category enriched over a *particular* Heyting algebra, rather than over the category *of* Heyting algebras (which is what "Heyt-enriched category" would normally mean).  You might be interested in Joyal-Tierney *On an extension of the Galois theory of Grothendieck* where they study modules over monoids in suplattices as an analogue of rings; I don't remember exactly what they correspond to in the localic world in that generality, but I think there is something.

Comment: Yes, I meant a category enriched over a single $H$, sorry :-) thanks for the ref!